# Generating a probability distribution P(y) from another probability distribution P(x) such that highest probability in P(x) is least likely in P(y)

Tags: python, random, probability, probability-distribution, numpy-random

So the problem at hand is that I have some values in  a dictionary with counters, let's say

```
dict = {"cats":0, "dogs":0, "lions":0}
```

I want to randomly select the keys from this dictionary and increment the counters as I select the particular keys.

But as I select the keys and increment the counters for those keys, I want the probability of selection to be higher of the keys whose counter values are lesser than the other keys.

I have implemented this idea in my answer below. Kindly let me know if this makes sense and if there are any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Does your answer/solution satisfy your requirements? Does it pass all the tests you designed for it? Are looking for an open ended critique? Why did you choose to post your solution as an Answer instead of including it in your question?

Comment: @wwii I have come up with this solution to the problem in the question and I want to know if other people have some other ideas on solving this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **many** ways of solving this, but as an alternative I'd be tempted to calculate the probabilities as:

```
def iweight(k, *, alpha=1):
    p = 1/(alpha + np.array(k))
    return p / np.sum(p)
```

which could be used as:

```
counts = [0, 0, 0, 20]
for _ in range(20):
    i = np.random.choice(len(counts), p=iweight(counts))
    print(i)
    counts[i] += 1
```

the `alpha` is used in a complementary way to a [Dirichlet process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_process): small values will cause it to prefer drawing values from small counts, while large values will cause it to be more uniform.

What's best will depend on the process you're modelling, e.g. how much should small counts be preferred to medium counts, should the largest counts ever be chosen, etc.  It all depends on the distribution you're after and the statistics literature should have many examples of how to start thinking about this.

Comment: Thanks for showing me another way to do this and taking out time to write down the code. 

I read into the Dirichlet process thanks to your explanation. Using the process you explained, I have more control over the importance I want to give larger difference in counts using the alpha parameter.

So should I be using your method or the one I came up with? 
What would the distribution, that I am making using softmax values, be called? In comparison to you making the Dirichlet distribution.

Comment: @ZaidTahir there aren't that many well-known/named distributions...  your sum of exponentials reminds me of the Gibbs distribution, but it's not a great match.  You should use the one that most closely matches whatever it is you're trying to do!  e.g. if it's just for fun, it doesn't really matter.  if you've got data you're trying to reproduce, then compare summary stats of the data to the alternatives and pick whichever is "best" for you